# understanding xcopy command

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am modifying a batch script to move a directory from one place to another.  In the batch code, there are these two lines. I don't understand the first parts

`echo xcopy %SOURCE_FILE% %TARGET_FILE% /Y /Z /C /F 1>>"%logfile%" 2>&1`

`echo F|xcopy %SOURCE_FILE% %TARGET_FILE% /Y /Z /C /F 1>>"%logfile%" 2>&1`

1. Do these lines of code execute the copy or just write out to the log file?  I ask this because the code currently copies, however, there is no line of xcopy without the echo in front.
2. In line two what does `F|xcopy` mean?
3. Other then the `F|xcopy` on the second line, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first writes the command it is about to execute to a log file, but does nothing useful.

The second actually executes XCOPY but answers the question that gets asked with the letter "F" presumably when XCOPY asks "Do you mean Files or Directories?"

Comment: A follow up question: So, I am copying a directory with other directories and files, with the |F work to copy all of them?

Comment: It will do exactly the same as if you type the XCOPY command without the "ECHO F |" and hit Enter, and then type "F" once (followed by  Enter) when asked a question.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, could you please accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick? Otherwise, please say what didn't work, so I (and others) can help you further.

Comment: I will make a decision once I can succesfully run my script.  Right now I am attempting to execute it from a java progam, which hasn't been too successful.

Comment: I am now using xcopy `S:\%FOLDER% T:\%FOLDER% /E /I /H` to copy all the subdirectories. Thank tou for your help

Answer (score 1):

`|`is a pipe-symbol. It passes the output from the command before to the command after.

So the result of `echo F` (which is `F`) to the xcopy-command. So if xopy asks the user for input, it gets "F".

Simple example:

```
echo . | pause
```

Try it, `pause` waits for a keystroke, but `echo .` deliveres this keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

1. just the report of what is to be done. better to use the `/L` switch on `xcopy`.
2. `echo f|` means to reply to a potential prompt with "f". The prompt is going to be "is the destination a directory or a file" the response is "file"
3. The first reports only, the second executes.

Comment: In response to 3:
If the first one is waiting for "f" and never gets it, does it time out and move on to the second one?

Comment: No - it waits for a response. That might be a bit of a game since the prompt is likely redirected to the file.